# Scrapy: skip hrefs w/ missing scheme

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

So I'm trying to crawl the popular.ebay.com page and I get an `error:Missing scheme in request url: #mainContent` for the # anchor links.

The following is my code:

```
def parse_links(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = hxs.select('//a')
    #domain = 'http://popular.ebay.com/'
    for link in links:
        anchor_text = ''.join(link.select('./text()').extract())
        title = ''.join(link.select('./@title').extract())
        url = ''.join(link.select('./@href').extract())
        meta = {'title':title,}
        meta = {'anchor_text':anchor_text,}
        yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)
```

I can't add the base url to #mainContent, because it adds a double URL to the urls with with the full url scheme.  I end up getting urls like this `http://popular.ebay.comhttp://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=grande+mansion`

```
def parse_links(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = hxs.select('//a')
    #domain = 'http://popular.ebay.com/'
    for link in links:
        anchor_text = ''.join(link.select('./text()').extract())
        title = ''.join(link.select('./@title').extract())
        url = ''.join(link.select('./@href').extract())
        meta = {'title':title,}
        meta = {'anchor_text':anchor_text,}
        yield Request(response.url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)
```

The links I want to get look like this: `<a href="http://popular.ebay.com/antiques/antique-chair/antique-chairs.htm" title="Antique Chairs">Antique Chairs | </a>` but I get the error cause of links like this: `<a id="gh-hdn-stm" class="gh-acc-a" href="#mainContent">Skip to main content</a>`

How would I go about adding the base url to only the hash anchor links, or ignore links without the base url in them?  For a simple solution I've tried the set rule `deny=(#mainContent)` and `restrict_xpaths`, but the crawler still spits the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error:Missing scheme in request url: #mainContent` is caused by requesting a url without a scheme (the "http://" part of the url).

#mainContent is an internal link, referring to a HTML element with the id "mainContent". You're probably not wanting to follow these links, as it's only linking to a different part of the current page you're on.

I'd suggest looking at this part of the documentation http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml.SgmlLinkExtractor. You can tell Scrapy to follow links which conform to a certain format and restrict what part of the page it will fetch links from. Take note of the "restrict_xpaths" and "allow" parameters.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yup, I understand where the error is coming from and I've tried setting deny rules and restrict_xpaths, but it still has the same error.  I cannot use allow, unless I write out every url category I'm trying to crawl.

Comment: allow can take a regular expression, you could construct some regex to ignore links which start with a "#" :)

Comment: I didn't know regex could ignore! What a great workaround!  Let me try that and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert at regex, but would something as simple as this do the trick /^http/

Comment: Unfortunately, scrapy still needs the scheme for the URL.

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop:

```
meta = {'anchor_text':anchor_text,}
url = link.select('./@href').extract()[0]
if not '#' in url: // or if url[0] != '#'
    yield Request(response.url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)
```

This will avoid yielding `#foobar` as an URL. You could add the base url to the `#foobar` in an `else` statement, but since this will redirect to a page scrapy has already scraped I don't  think there's a point in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found links other than #mainContent that were missing the scheme, so using @Robin's logic I made sure that the url contained the base url before parse_page.

```
    for link in links:
        anchor_text = ''.join(link.select('./text()').extract())
        title = ''.join(link.select('./@title').extract())
        url = ''.join(link.select('./@href').extract())
        meta = {'title':title,}
        meta = {'anchor_text':anchor_text,}
        if domain in url:
            yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)
```